# Ordering a triming (pagination) a big array, how?

Tags: list, algorithm, memory

a classic task, I need to return a list which can be paginated.

Here is the elements:

```
ecgdfahb
```

lets order it:

```
abcdefgh
```

and I want to return the first page, with 2 items:

```
ab
```

or the 2nd page:

```
cd
```

so basically I just add source items, order them and make a simple array-split operation (data dont come from database).
But this list is huge. Way too huge, and with doing this, I get memory overflow when I try to add the 5. elements. Is there a memory-sparing approach of it? If there would no be pages, then it would be simple, because only the non-crowded out elements would be in list.

Comment: External merge sort? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting#External_merge_sort

Comment: Is the list constant (sort once) or do you want to add elements and keep it sorted?

Comment: yea, I want to add the element and keep it sorted

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use a RDBMS and to write a SQL query like:

```
SELECT x FROM table
ORDER by x
LIMIT window_size OFFSET window_offset
```

Be sure to have a B-tree index on the field `table.x`. The main interest of B-trees is that they require a small amount of disk access and keep the list of values sorted.

If you don't want to use a RDBMS, you'll have implement the B-tree yourself. See the [wikipedia page on B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) for general information. There is also a good chapter in [Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).

To summarize, a B-tree is a like a binary tree, but its nodes have a lot of children, let's say up to `m`. Hence, those trees are shallower than binary trees. Nodes are stored on disk (typically, each node is saved on a disk block), allowing you to store ordered lists of values that don't fit into memory. If you have `n` keys `x1, ... xn` in a non-leaf node, then you have `n+1` children nodes, containing values `<= x1` values between `x1` and `x2`, .... The main difficulty is to insert values: when the number of values in a node exceeds `m`, you have to split that node.

Some references: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Algorithms and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-b-tree-2/.

To ouput a given window, use a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to find the start index and continue until you found the last index of the window.

Comment: yea looks like that will be the case.